# To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files: - CyberPanel

Tags: php, composer-php, php-extension, php-ini, cyber-panel

When I try intall composer, this error shows:

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files

I'm using CyberPanel

[image]

so I run this command, but got error.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4 libapache2-mod-php7.4 php7.4-common php7.4-gd php7.4-mysql php7.4-curl php7.4-intl php7.4-xsl php7.4-mbstring php7.4-zip php7.4-bcmath php7.4-soap php-xdebug php-imagick
```

[image]

Comment: Please always share the error messages **in text form**. Also, keep in mind that PHP 7.4 is outdated. The error messages from the second screenshot are completely unrelated to Composer